# How to restrict a user from entering digits after 2 decimal points - Angular

Tags: angular, format, decimal, blur

I have the below code which has the input field, I am validating the value using RegEx and the regex used is /^\d{1,2}.([0-9]|[0-9][0-9]{1})$/

The field allows the user to enter more than 2 digits after decimal point, and throws a validation error. But what I actually need is to restrict the user from entering any further digits after 2 digits are entered after decimal point.

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" [floatLabel]="'always'">
                <input matInput formControlName="bathsNum" [(ngModel)]="noOfbaths" (blur)="formatBathsNum($event)">
              </mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use power of directive to accomplish this behavior, Here I have attached directive we are using in our project. We have made it quite extensive incase in any place we want more than 2 decimal point.

Also, on how directive works is very simple:

- it listens to keypress event and check if decimal place is exceeded or not along with restriction of accepting only numbers in input field.
- Also, it handles in case user copies the value directly into input box. which is handled by `onBlur` event.

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Renderer2, Input, OnInit, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[fixDecimal]'
})
export class FixDecimalDirective implements OnInit {


  @Input('validDecimal') validDecimal?: number = 2;
  @Input('autoFixed') autoFixed?: boolean = true;
  @Input('isAllowNegative') isAllowNegative?: boolean = false;
  @Input() ngModel: any;

  currentElement: ElementRef;
  elementRenderer: Renderer2;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {
    this.currentElement = el;
    this.elementRenderer = renderer;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    if (!this.ngModel) {
      return;
    }
  }

  @HostListener('blur', ['$event.target.value']) onBlur(value) {
    if(value) {
      if (this.autoFixed) {
        if (value || value == 0) {
          value = parseFloat(value).toFixed(this.validDecimal);
        }
      } else {
        if (value[0] === '.') {
          value = parseFloat(value);
        }
      }
      if (isNaN(value)) {
        value = '0';
      }
      this.currentElement.nativeElement.value = parseFloat(value).toFixed(this.validDecimal);
    }
  }

  @HostListener('keypress', ['$event']) onKeypress(event) {
    const currentDecimalCount = this.countDecimalPlaces(this.currentElement.nativeElement.value);
    if (event.keyCode === 32 || (event.keyCode === 45 && !this.isAllowNegative) || currentDecimalCount >= this.validDecimal) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }

  countDecimalPlaces(number) {
    if (isNaN(number) || Number.isInteger(number)) {
      return 0;
    } else {
      const decimalPart = String(number).split('.')[1];
      return decimalPart ? decimalPart.length : 0;
    }
  }

}
```